# Has there ever been a depiction of a futurist in Star Wars Legends or Canon?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, technology, science, society

I love futurism and even though Star Wars is more science-fantasy than sci-fi; they DO have technology and science and scientists are often featured in various stories. Philosophers are also mentioned. Has there ever been a depiction of someone who prognosticates the future of society and technology in the stories? I’ve yet to find an example on Wookieepedia and other databanks

Comment: Most of the Sith and the Jedi can see the future of society to some extent through their connection to the Force. For instance, Palpatine prognosticates that "Once more the Sith will rule the galaxy! And we shall have peace."

Comment: Yeah I know but they usually see things more related to the fates of individuals and the visions usually come at random

Answer (score 0):

At least the premise exists in Star Wars

https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Starlight_(song)

Comment: Are you the same Max who asked this question? If so, please [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), so that you can fully interact with all of your questions and answers using the same account.

Comment: Ok. I will. Thanks!